# C# Is it possible to add methods to super classes

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In ruby and some others, its possible to add a new method to pre-existing  ancestor class  and all the descendants inherit them.  I'm wondering if that's possible in C# as well.

For example, I would like to add a few methods to the Page class in Xamarin.Forms which would make them automatically available on all NavigationPages ContentPages and other descendants of Page.  Can you do that sort of thing in C#?

Comment: Yes, sort of, by using "extension methods".

Comment: Thanks Enigmativity that helps.  Seems like it will do the trick although slightly tedious to have to put the "using" clause in every module where I want to leverage the extension method.

Comment: @user1023110 - No more tedious than having to put a `using` clause for any class you need to reference.

Comment: That's true, I thought it was somehow required keyword even if the extension method is defined in the same namespace.   Apparently not, so that works really well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, sort of, by using "Extension Methods":

```
void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    Console.WriteLine(foo.GetDoubleBar());
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Bar => 42;
}

// Defined somewhere else in your code
public static class FooEx
{
    public static int GetDoubleBar(this Foo foo) => foo.Bar * 2;
}
```

The `this` keyword in the `static` `GetDoubleBar` in the `static` class `FooEx` defines an extension method.

When run this outputs `84`.